# Как запретить редактирование, но разрешить копирование ячеек DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть DataGridView. Как запретить редактирование ячеек, но разрешить копирование?

Comment: Вроде бы [`dataGridView.ReadOnly=true;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx) не запрещает копирование. Или Вы как то по другому отключаете редактирование?